# Время выполнения методов

Tags: php

Есть класс. Хочется узнать, сколько времени при вызове выполняются разные методы этого класса. (т.е. чтобы вывелось echo-м на экран 'время выполнения метода M -  n секунд'). Как это лучше реализовать? 
(Интересует только время выполнения вызванных методов (их может быть много в классе, нужен универсальный механизм), а не всего скрипта в целом)

UPD.
Реализовал так:
1) runkit + ReflectionMethod (который вытягивает код метода для runkit)  добавил в мой новый метод класса ( назвал before_calling)
 Сам метод (before_calling) добавляет вверху $start = microtime(true); и внизу $time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start; echo 'Время выполнения метода '.$time_elapsed_secs.'сек';
2) В конструкторе вытянул все методы класса ( функция get_class_methods)
3) Там же foreach пробежал все полученные методы класса и вызвал для каждого метод before_calling. В итоге, при вызове любого метода на экран выводится сообщение о времени выполнения метода.

Может кому-то понадобится.

Comment: Общее время для скрипта в целом понятно, но меня интересует, чтобы конкретно  для метода ,который был вызван

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: Вставляете вызов microtime в начало и конец метода и обрабатываете результат, как показано в вопросе по ссылке. Будет Вам счастье. Так что по сути Ваша задача сводится к **уже существующему** вопросу. Или используйте xDebug, как предлагают выше.

Comment: Не хочу вставлять в каждый метод microtime. Их может быть сотни. Xdubug тоже не решает проблему, так как его нужно будет вставлять в каждый метод. Нужен универсальный вариант!
 Может есть какой, с использованием магических методов или других, которые бы срабатывали в начале и в конце выполнения метода, и брали бы разницу во времени?

Comment: "Xdubug тоже не решает проблему, так как его нужно будет вставлять в каждый метод." - вы бы, прежде чем ерунду говорить, почитали бы документацию чтоли

Comment: Использование profiler не совсем интересен, если вы имеете ввиду, что он данные сохраняет в файл, а потом этот файл анализировать IDE или другой программой. Необходимо чтобы визуально был вывод echo на экране. Если есть такая возможность у xdebug в контексте моего изначального вопроса, то подскажите

Comment: Ваше "Я не хочу" с учётом того, что в PHP нет возможностей, которые вы хотите, выглядит достаточно странно. Выбирайте из предложенных в комментариях альтернатив -- а вопрос нужно закрыть, так как нет чётких критериев, какой вариант считать наилучшим.

Comment: Критерий в том, чтобы не использовать xdebug (он грузит на продакшене сервер) и визуально и быстро увидеть время выполнения метода.

Answer (score 1):

Может это корявый способ, но можно получить отметку времени через microtime() перед выполнением метода и после, а потом узнать разницу и получить результат в микросекундах.

Comment: я бы не назвал этот способ "универсальным"